# UILabel value is empty when I tap a button in basic calculator code

Tags: ios, swift

According to piece of my simple calc code: when I tap to number1, UILabel value will be 1 after then I tap to add button and first variable will be 1 and UILabel value and UILabel screen become empty (due to MyLabel.text = "").
On the other hand, original IOS calculator working logic is different. when someone tap add button. First variable value is not disappear from Label and when you change the operator to divide or something. First value of variable is still in memory. what is logic behind this? I've been searching lots of code in java, etc but I every sample is like mine. provide a clue please ?

```
@IBOutlet var MyLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func numberOneTapped (sender: UIButton) {
            if  MyLabel.text == "0" {
                MyLabel.text = "1" } else {
                MyLabel.text = MyLabel.text! + "1"
                }
}
... 
@IBAction func addTapped (sender: UIButton) {
    operant = "add"
    var var1 = "\(MyLabel.text!)" as NSString
    num1 = var1.doubleValue
    MyLabel.text = ""
}
@IBAction func equalTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    if operant == "add" {
        var num2 = ("\(MyLabel.text!)") as NSString
        var2 = num2.doubleValue
        MyLabel.text = "\(var1 + var2)"
      }
```

Comment: Where is `num1` declared?

Comment: Hi, num1 is initialized in the beginning of code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a state variable to your calculator.

```
var state:CalculatorState = .EqualJustPressed
```

Some recommended states are:

```
enum CalculatorState {
    case EqualJustPressed
    case FirstNumberStarted
    case OperatorJustEntered
    case SecondNumberStarted
}
```

Then you can keep track of what is happening at all times with your calculator.

1. Start your calculator in state `.EqualJustPressed` with `var1 = 0` and a `"0"` in the text field.
2. If you are in `.EqualJustPressed` state, and the user types a digit, set the field to the digit and switch to state `.FirstNumberStarted`.  If the user types an operator in `.EqualJustPressed` state, store the value of the field in `var1`, record the operator, and go to `.OperatorJustEntered`.
3. If you are in `.FirstNumberStarted` state and the user enters a digit, just append it to the field.  If they enter an operator, record the operator, set the state to `.OperatorJustEntered` and store the value of the field in `var1`.
4. If they are in `.OperatorJustEntered` and they type a digit, set the field to the digit and switch the state to `.SecondNumberStarted`.  If they hit another operator, just record the operator.
5. If they are in `.SecondNumberStarted` and they enter a digit, just append it to the field.  If they hit `=`, set `var2` to the value of the field, compute the result and put it into the field and set the state to `.EqualJustPressed`.  If they hit an operator while in `.SecondNumberStarted`, treat it just like the `=` case, but set `var1` to the result and set the state to `.OperatorJustEntered`.

By using an enum to keep track of the state of your calculator, you can easily reason *"what do I want to happen here"* for each state.

Note:  You never set the field to empty `""` with this model.  The field always has either the most recent result of a calculation or the number they are currently entering, just like a real calculator.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you find my answer addresses you question, please tick the checkmark to the left of my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your advise. I resolved my problem after 3 hours working last night. Actually, I added second UILabel in my code (Probably,default calculator app of iphone has it also. But this label is hiding while calc is running. ) And, I got

Comment: Post your solution as an answer. You are allowed to answer your own question and it can help others.